# First use of SWI-Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm brand new to Prolog. I am simply trying to get some output from Prolog on Windows Vista.

I have downloaded and installed Prolog 5.1; I chose the .pro file extension when installing (not to confuse with Perl files).

I created a file called `test.pro`. 
Inside this file I put the following:

```
inside(tom).
?-inside(tom).
```

I double clicked the file and a command line interface popped up. On this interface (after a bunch of generic Prolog version/copyright info) the only output is:

```
1 ?-
```

OK, for starters, I did not expect it to *ask* a question;  I expected it to *answer* a question (something along the line of 'yes').

Anyway, I tried to respond to the query with the following:

In the command line I re-inserted 'inside(tom).', so the whole line looks like:

```
1 ?- inside(tom).
```

I pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> and got an error message:

```
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: inside/1 (DWIM could not correct goal)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to compile this first (also called "consult" in prolog).  If I knew which version of prolog you have I could find out the exact key entry for this command (Ctrl-L may work). By the way, welcome to the wonderful world of prolog- I love it :) As soon as you're over this hurdle, it gets a lot better. :)

Comment: I'm guessing this is SWI-Prolog ( you might be surprised at how many different 'prologs' there are). In which case, "Consult..." is on the main file menu- it prompts you for a file to load so just reload this file and you should be all set. You do, indeed, have to ask it a query  before it will do anything- that's how any prolog program works.

Comment: Yes, SWI-Prolog. I found that and I think I compiled the file.  At first when I chose the 'consult' option from the file menu, I did not see my file named test.pro.  I had to choose to view "All Files" (that's wierd, maybe prolog is not recognizing .pro files) for the file to become apparent; I chose it and it seemed to comiple. I was given the message: "dir.../test.pro compiled 0.00 sec, 1,696 bytes", but I did not see a compiled file in the same directory and am currently searching through the new directory structure that was installed with the Prolog installation.

Comment: I reinstalled SWI-Prolog, but left the default for file extension to .pl . That seemed to be the problem ... in addition to compiling via menu 'file/consult' as you suggested. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 22):

Prolog doesn't answer questions if you haven't told it *facts*. (Except for some built-in facts such as `member(1, [1,2,3])`.)

You can tell it who is inside by (comment follow a `%`):

```
1 ?- [user].                          % get facts and rules from user input
|: inside(mary).                      % Mary and John are explicitly inside
|: inside(john).
|: inside(X) :- location(X, house).   % rule: anyone in the house is inside
|: inside(X) :- location(X, office).  % (variables start with a capital letter)
|: 
|: location(tom, house).
|: location(bernard, house).
|: location(anne, office).
|:                                    % type Ctrl+D
% user://1 compiled 0.00 sec, 1,220 bytes
true.

2 ?- inside(tom).                     % Prolog deduces that Tom is inside
true .
```

If you want to learn Prolog, [*Learn Prolog Now*](http://learnprolognow.org/) is a good, free tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty. What was missing was 'compiling' the file, known as consult
and the syntax is as follows, all characters in the line are relevant.

?- [filename].

then you can ask questions and do other things with what the database.(the source code in prolog)

http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=quickstart